# DTO, Interface- Get specific object element form array of object

Tags: json, typescript, javascript-objects

I have below array that I am getting from API call.

```
[{"id":1,"todo":"Do something nice for someone I care about","completed":true,"userId":26},{"id":2,"todo":"Memorize the fifty states and their capitals","completed":false,"userId":48},{"id":3,"todo":"Watch a classic movie","completed":false,"userId":4},{"id":4,"todo":"Contribute code or a monetary donation to an open-source software project","completed":false,"userId":48},{"id":5,"todo":"Solve a Rubik's cube","completed":false,"userId":31},{"id":6,"todo":"Bake pastries for me and neighbor","completed":false,"userId":39}]
```

Now I only need id and todo in another array  at component level,
for eg:

```
[{"id":1,"todo":"Do something nice for someone I care about"},{"id":2,"todo":"Memorize the fifty states and their capitals"}]
```

but I need to handle it using either Interface or DTO how should I achieve it.
or is there any another way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can just the array operation [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which we can use to take the required properties for each element and will return a new array which you can assign to a variable!

```js
apiCallData = [{
  "id": 1,
  "todo": "Do something nice for someone I care about",
  "completed": true,
  "userId": 26
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "todo": "Memorize the fifty states and their capitals",
  "completed": false,
  "userId": 48
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "todo": "Watch a classic movie",
  "completed": false,
  "userId": 4
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "todo": "Contribute code or a monetary donation to an open-source software project",
  "completed": false,
  "userId": 48
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "todo": "Solve a Rubik's cube",
  "completed": false,
  "userId": 31
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "todo": "Bake pastries for me and neighbor",
  "completed": false,
  "userId": 39
}];

const anotherArray = apiCallData.map(x => ({
  id: x.id,
  todo: x.todo
}));
console.log(anotherArray);
```

Comment: This is exactly right. Note it has nothing to do with interfaces or DTOs.

Comment: Hi Thanks  for the solution, This question is asked in one interview and I am not sure is it a trick question or there is any way to implement it using interface or/and DTO. I am trying find solution for it but no luck so far